# Simple example of LogSpace reduction

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, reductions

In general, how can I verify that my many-one reduction is a LogSpace reduction? E.g. I was looking at the proof of [HORN-SAT is P-complete via logspace reduction](https://logic.rwth-aachen.de/files/KTQC/KTQC-chapter3.pdf#page=13).

It would be ok even if someone makes me a simple example of LogSpace reduction clearly explaining why it is LogSpace and not polynomial.

Many thanks.

Comment: Every logspace reduction is polynomial.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, I meant *just* polinomial. E.g. a polynomial time reduction would not be ok for proving HORN-SAT is P-complete, right?

Comment: If the reduction can be implemented so that is uses only logarithmic space, then it is logspace.